# wait and scroll commands in Ruby Calabash

Tags: ios, ruby, calabash

I would explain a bit more in detail.I have one page booking widget.my code comes to this page.then the code should wait for the page to load.Then the code should scroll down to enter email address in the text box.Thats my requirement.The script fails as the code is not waiting for page to load and also cannot scroll to the bottom.So I need proper commands to use for this requirement.Many thanks everyone

Comment: It would help a lot of you share what test script you have now. What will often happen is that the framework will tell you that loading finished, but it has not. So you need to add some forced sleep.

Answer (score -1):

You better choose one of the elements from the page and wait until that element loads, for an example, let's assume there is a button in that page, So you write the following code like this

```
b.button(:id,'something').wait_until_present
```

Now your code wait until this button is available, So it automatically waits until that page loads.

Now coming to scrolling problem, Use the gem watir-scroll. Once you require this gem, you can use the following code to scroll the page

```
b.scroll.to b.button(:id,'something')
```

So the aforementioned code scroll the page to this button.

Comment: I down voted because this is a Calabash question and you answered with non-calabash syntax.  There is no calabash `wait_until_present`.